# How to simplify an ideal (f,g) division with remainder

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, euclidean-domain

suppose we have an ideal $(f,g)\subseteq K[X]$ for an euclidean domain $K$.
Where $f,g\in K[X]$. 
Can we always simplify the ideal by using division with remainder?

Example:

$(1+x^2, 5+x^3)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}[X]$
It is $(1+x^2, 5+x^3)=(x-5, 26)$

How do we attempt the division with remainder?

$(x^3+5)\div (x^2+1)=x~~ R~~5-x$ ($R~~ 5-x$ means that the remainder is $5-x$)

Since $x^3+5=x(x^2+1)+(5-x)$

Now we use a 2nd division with remainder:

$(x^2+1)\div (-x+5)= -x+5~~ R~~ 26$

Since $x^2+1=(-x+5)(-x-5)+26$

And we conclude $(x^3+5, x^2+1)=(x-5, 26)$

Can this always be done? We need an euclidean domain for this, right? (Else we can not use division with remainder)
The "algorithm" is always(?) like above?

We first divide $f\div g$  (with $\deg f\geq \deg g$) and get a remainder $R_1$, then we divide
$g$ by $R_1$ and get a remainder $R_2$ and our ideal reduces too:

$(f,g)=(R_1, R_2)$

Can you approve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> suppose we have an ideal $(f,g)\subseteq K[X]$ for an euclidean domain $K$.
>   Where $f,g\in K[X]$. 
>   Can we always simplify the ideal by using division with remainder?

Yes, in a Euclidean domain, you can always divide one nonzero element by another, and simplify every set of generators of an ideal to a single element that generates the entire ideal.

> Example:
>   $(1+x^2, 5+x^3)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}[X]$ ...

You *do* realize that $\mathbb Z[x]$ is *not* a Euclidean domain, right?

> Can this always be done? We need an euclidean domain for this, right? (Else we can not use division with remainder)
>   The "algorithm" is always(?) like above?

You can always divide by a monic polynomial in any polynomial ring $R[x]$. You don't *have* to have a Euclidean domain to do that.  The division you did does in fact produce an equivalent set of generators with lesser degrees in cases like you describe.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not euclidean. (It is not a principal domain, so it can not be euclidean).

Comment: So I do not need an euclidean domain to reduce ideals in general?

Comment: @Cornman You can attempt reduction with any monic polynomial. But if you have something like $(2x^2+1, 5x^3)\subseteq \mathbb Z[x]$ then you are up a creek without a paddle.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out when this works when you have an ideal $(f,g)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Answer (score 1):

I guess not. Remember that $\mathbf{Z}[x]$ is not an euclidean domain. In fact, $I = (2, x)$ is not principal. So, it's not possible do this algorithm for every pairs of polynomials. If $F$ is a field, then $F[x]$ is euclidean. At this case, if $I=(f,g)$ with $\deg f \geq \deg g$, there is $q, r \in F[x]$ such that $f = q g + r$ and $\deg r < \deg g$ or $r = 0$. So $(f, g) = (r, g)$. We can continue this process and it'll end in a finite number of steps. Everything is ok and you can prove that I is principal. It's not a surprise: we can use [Bezout's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#For_principal_ideal_domains) to obtain $I = (\gcd(f, g))$.

Note that the only problem with your algorithm is the existence of a division process.